# Creating a function which iterates through dataframe rows, applies a scipy function, appends the output to a new column and outputs modified dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, helper

Forgive me if this question seems to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer that matches my exact requirements:

I have a dataframe of z-scores, named "df", which is structured as follows:

```
    score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
1   0.15    0.20    0.81    0.60
2   0.70    0.55    0.84    0.50
3   0.90    0.33    0.54    0.07
```

I would like to create a new column, "z_score_combined", which has the combined z-scores of each row.

In this instance, the z-scores would be combined using the "combine_pvalues" function from scipy.stats. *For more information read: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.combine_pvalues.html*

The function is structured as follows:

```
combine_pvalues(z-score-array, method='stouffer', weights=None)
```

In the function, "z-score-array" is an array of the z-scores from each row. For example "array_1" would be an array of the z-scores from the row indexed 1 in "df"; i.e. array_1 = [(0.15, 0.20, 0.81, 0.60)], array_2 = [(0.70, 0.55, 0.84, 0.50)] and so on.

How would I create a helper function which:

1. Iterates through the rows of the dataframe, "df";
2. Creates a 1D Numpy array object, "z-score-array";
3. Feeds the array into the function: combine_pvalues(z-score-array, method='stouffer', weights=None), for calculation of the combined z_score;
4. Appends the combined z-score to the "z_score_combined" new column in the dataframe, "df";
5. Outputs an altered version dataframe "df" with the new column of combined z-scores.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: only one answer should  be accepted, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `df.apply` . You can create a function that accepts a row and each row can access the attributes from columns 1-4. This omits the need of creating an array for zscores since you are iterating over those rows. This function should return the value supposed to go in the combined_z_score column for that row. Then create the new column as:

df['new_column'] = df.apply(your_function, axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function, if want one column select first `[0]` or second value `[1]` of tuples:

```
from scipy.stats import combine_pvalues
df['pval'] = df.apply(lambda x: combine_pvalues(x, method='stouffer', weights=None)[1], axis=1)
print (df)
   score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4      pval
1     0.15     0.20     0.81     0.60  0.354423
2     0.70     0.55     0.84     0.50  0.794535
3     0.90     0.33     0.54     0.07  0.394789
```

If want output 2 values in 2 columns add parameter `result_type='expand'`:

```
from scipy.stats import combine_pvalues

f = lambda x: combine_pvalues(x, method='stouffer', weights=None)
df[['stat','pval']] = df.apply(f, axis=1, result_type='expand')
print (df)
   score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4      stat      pval
1     0.15     0.20     0.81     0.60  0.373406  0.354423
2     0.70     0.55     0.84     0.50 -0.822260  0.794535
3     0.90     0.33     0.54     0.07  0.266859  0.394789
```